# change image on click() using jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends trying to change the image after click on link but failed to do. The scenario is I build a menu each tab has different image in grey colour I want when user click on that tha grey image would turn into white and when user click on another tab then earlier white image go back to grey colour and new image will turn white you can check my code below or **[can see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UBfmy/)**

**HTML**

```
<ul data-role="list-divider" class="footerMenu">
        <li><a href="#">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/6fnxrzxu9/friends_Icon.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " />
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/7j823yihd/friends_Iconwh.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " class="active"/><br />
          Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/5we94zh1t/cards_Icon.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " />
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/mivte29zl/cards_Iconwh.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " class="active" /><br />
          Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/vt7xhlkpd/egreeting_Icon.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " />
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/lacj667f5/egreeting_Iconwh.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" "  class="active"/><br />
          Egreeting</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/hukewma6p/post.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " />
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/nk0ngxgcx/postwh.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " class="active" /><br />
          Post</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/4jwk33jm9/custom_Icon.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" " />
        <img src="http://s16.postimg.org/qkcwjq2a9/custom_Iconwh.png" width="114" height="77" alt=" "  class="active"/><br />
          Custom</a></li>
      </ul>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$('.footerMenu li a').on('click', function () {


    $('.footerMenu li a').children('img.active').each(function(index, element) {
        $(this).css('display','none');
    });

    //$('.footerMenu li a img.active').hide();  
    //$(this).children('img').css('display','none');
    $(this).children('img.active').css('display','inline');

    if($(this).children('img:not(.active)').css('display')== 'none')
    {   $(this).children('img:not(.active)').css('display','inline');
        }
        else

    {   $(this).children('img:not(.active)').css('display','none');
            }


})
```

**CSS**

```
body{background:red;}
.footerMenu img.active{display:none;}
```

Please help me guys..Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $as = $('.footerMenu li a'), $imgs = $as.find('img');
$as.on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this), $cimgs = $this.find('img');
    $as.find('img:first-child').removeClass('active');
    $as.find('img:gt(0)').addClass('active');
    $cimgs.eq(1).removeClass('active');
    $cimgs.eq(0).addClass('active');
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jLMgd/)